# Storing java date and time into the records everytime I run the program

Tags: java, date, time

I am trying to build a Java Application and as part of this application, I'd want to make a note of the date and time of when an incident has occurred. The current code that I am using looks something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> list=new LinkedList<>();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now=LocalDateTime.now();
    String formatDateTime=now.format(formatter);
    list.add(formatDateTime);
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(formatDateTime);


}
```

The output of this program looks something like this now:

[06-16-2017 20:35:51]
06-16-2017 20:35:51

However, this is not what I am expecting. I want to store the date and time that has been recorded but the output of this code differs every time I run it. Is there any way I could store the date and time individually every time the program runs. To make the question a bit clear, if I run the program initially at 20:35:51, I want this time to be stored. If I run it at 20:36:52, I still want the 1st time to be available in my records. Please help me out on this. Thanks.

Comment: Is this for a real, production system, or just investigation? If the latter, as Dan answered, just write (in append mode) to a file. If it is a true production system, you might want to post a metric to a monitoring application.

Comment: Hi, it's just an investigation that I am trying to do here. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Will you need the first time to be available in your program the second time it runs? Or should just both times be available to yourself after the two program runs? Are you really after a logging facility?

Comment: If you need to keep the list in your program from run to run, you may look into serialization or a database.

Comment: By the way, for logging, it is generally best to keep your date-times in the [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone and create text using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats: `Instant.now().toString()`. Also, you may eventually want to consider the use of logging frameworks, probably [slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org) with [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch).

Answer (score 1):

You have to store your dates somewhere, otherwise when your program ends the variables (and your list of dates) are freed from memory and lost.

Maybe write to a .txt or .csv file? There's plenty of guides on how to do this online. You can then write a method to read all the dates from your file so you have a record of very time your 'event' occurred / your program was run.

Edit: 
I liked Vasyl's answer and the file explorer was nice but overkill, I think in this situation you don't care about specifying which file to write to every time the event occurs/program is run, you just want to spit it out to your text file.

Here's my suggestion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String formatDateTime = now.format(formatter);
    list.add(formatDateTime);
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(formatDateTime);

    String recordPath = "Records.txt";
    BufferedWriter writer;
    FileWriter fw;

    try{
            fw = new FileWriter(recordPath, true);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            for(String str : list){
                writer.write(str);
                writer.newLine();
                writer.flush();
            }

            System.out.println("Done writing!");

            writer.close();
            fw.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I would rather have the .close() in a finally block but since we're working in main that's not possible. Ideally put this in its own class and method.

Output in the .txt file (after running tree times):

```
06-17-2017 03:38:25
06-17-2017 03:39:52
06-17-2017 03:40:06
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @gogetter007 have updated my answer with my solution

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to store in txt file:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


public class NewClass1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String formatDateTime = now.format(formatter);
        list.add(formatDateTime);
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(formatDateTime);

        File f = null;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
            out.println(list);
            out.println(formatDateTime);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
        }

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[06-16-2017 22:16:02]
06-16-2017 22:16:02
```

**IN THE FILE:**

```
[06-16-2017 22:16:02]
06-16-2017 22:16:02
[06-16-2017 22:17:29]
06-16-2017 22:17:29
```